# How to add Recycle Bin as a toolbar in taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, recycle-bin

I have been trying to add Recycle Bin to my taskbar through toolbar settings but it is just showing me an error.

Just for the context (i.e. if the problem is because of this), I removed the name of Recycle Bin and left just a blank there.

Error:
[image: Error].

Comment: _"Just for the context (i.e. if the problem is because of this), I removed the name of Recycle Bin and left just a blank there"_ - well, it's easy to test this and the error message seems very related, so why not test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted but you need to create a shortcut to the `Recycle Bin` and create the toolbar with the shortcut.

1. Create a shortcut to `Recycle Bin` somewhere out of the way.
2. Create a toolbar using the newly created shortcut.

[Source](https://www.alphr.com/add-recycle-bin-windows-10-taskbar/).

Comment: Thanks, Man! It worked absolutely great for me! Thanks a ton!